# Having hard time with local maximum of a f(x,y) function.

Tags: functions, partial-derivative

$f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2) * e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$

Calculating $\frac{\delta}{\delta x} = \frac{2x(1 - x^2 - y^2)}{e^{x^2 + y^2}}, \frac{\delta}{\delta y} = \frac{2y(1 - x^2 - y^2)}{e^{x^2 + y^2}}$ i got local minimum at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ but I cant get local maximum that wolfram states exists. All i get is $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ which doesn't give me that much. Any tips on that one?

Comment: Well, don't you get $y = \pm~ \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ and that agrees with WA?

Comment: I feel kinda lost, WA states that two specific points at x = y are maximums

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((x%5E2%2By%5E2)*e%5E(-(x%5E2%2By%5E2)))

Comment: The graph of $f$ is a volcano.  There's a min in the center, and a ring of max's (at  $x^2+y^2=1$.)

Comment: Alright, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = x^2+y^2 \implies f(x,y) = f(u) = ue^{-u}\implies f'(u) = e^{-u} - ue^{-u} = 0 \implies (1-u)e^{-u} = 0\implies u = 1\implies x^2+y^2 = 1$. So the max occurs at points on the unit circle.